# Flutter FirebaseFirestore: retrieving fields from an array of IDs

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve fields from multiple IDs that are stored in an array.
I have a collection of users, and in every user's document, there is an array of restaurant IDs of that user's owned restaurant as follows:

[image]

And each restaurant's document is one of those IDs in the array.
I successfully retrieved the array of ID's from the User but now I'm trying to get the names of the restaurant depending on the ID

[image]

**I'm retrieving my ID's using this code:**

```
  var restaurantIDs = [];
      
  getRestaurantIDs() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      restaurantIDs = value.data()['rid'];
    });
    return restaurantIDs;
  }
```

**Then I'm trying to retrieve the names and save them in an array using this code:**

```
  var restaurantNames = [];

  getRestaurantNames() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurantIDs.length; i++) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('restaurant')
          .doc(restaurantIDs[i])
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        restaurantNames = value.data()['name'];
      });
    }
    return restaurantNames;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?
and thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

1- I tried placing print statements inside the `for` loop, but it's like as if it's not going inside the loop at all, because the print statements don't get executed.

2- I think it's because the list of IDs won't be already stored inside the array when the function is called inside the `initState`, because I tried to print the length of the `restaurantIDs` array before the `for` loop and in `initState` and it showed 0, but when I print it inside the `Scaffold`, it would show 2.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried merging both functions into one to make sure that the `restaurantIDs` isn't empty, and now it goes inside the for loop because it prints out the statement, but now I receive another error

**new function:**

```
var restaurantIDs = [];
  var restaurantNames = [];

  getRestaurantIDs() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      restaurantIDs = value.data()['rid'];
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < restaurantIDs.length; i++) {
      print('added one');
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('restaurant')
          .doc(restaurantIDs[i])
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        restaurantNames.add(value.data()['name']);
      });
    }
    return restaurantNames;
  }
```

**Error:**

```
E/flutter (22920): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (22920): Receiver: null
E/flutter (22920): Tried calling: []("name")
E/flutter (22920): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)
E/flutter (22920): #1      _AddMealScreenState.getRestaurantIDs.<anonymous closure>
package:bits_n_bobs/screens/add_meal_item_screen.dart:178
E/flutter (22920): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (22920): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (22920): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22920): #4      _AddMealScreenState.getRestaurantIDs
E/flutter (22920): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22920):
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Did you check if `restaurantIDs` contains a list of ids?

Comment: I try to print out the Names, but it shows an empty array. Yes I checked the `restaurantIDs` and it contains an array of IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something a bit off about the way you have organized your database. For each restaurant document, you should create a key with the user id as value, and then simply use the **where** query.

Example :

```
final restaurants = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
        .collection("restaurant")
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: user.uid);            
        .get()
```

You can then map the retrieved list and filter the restaurant's name from it.

```
 final restaurantNames = data.docs
      .map((json) => 
            json.data()["name"])
      .toList();
```

Hope's that is hopefull.

Answer (score 1):

```
restaurantNames.add( value.data()['name']);
```

Check the document id is matching.

Comment: Still it would show an empty array when I try to print it.

Comment: maybe restaurantID not match. Try call only one id without loop.

Comment: Apparently, the IDs weren't matching, they start with the same letters, but then there is a slight difference after few characters, thanks for pointing it out... turns out I'm blind, now I fixed it though with another way using a Future

Comment: You welcome. Please, make my answer useful.